# Insert query in C# for GETDATE()

Tags: c#, sql, database

May i know how to access GETDATE() value  using insert query in C# (db connection), For Singe Cell in a row..

Every time i login into the page..Instead update, i use insert query to display time in gridview column  .. If i use update query i cant get list of search values filtered using date

I have four columns(one primary too) in that i want to change only fourth cell Getdate(). value using insert query its challenging i tried more cant get result

```
primarycol.  col1      col2       col3    Date(col4)

12345       aaa         4000.00   a121   2014-04-14 17:08:16.437
67890       bbb         3500.00   @121   2014-04-14 17:08:22.873
112233      ccc         2000.00   12345  2014-04-14 17:07:23.700
445566      ddd         6000.00   6789   2014-04-14 15:25:29.857


SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(("Insert into tablename (Date) values(GETDATE())"), con);
```

Init i want to insert again n again same datas ,rather then Date column

Comment: *warning* -- your approach may introduce sql injection attacks.

Comment: @DanielA.White, from a `DateTime` object, realy? I would understand if you discourage the use in other instances, but here?

Comment: @astander I think he just see `+` operator in sql query, not the value itself `:)`

Comment: @astander, Of course not from `DateTime` object, but it is bad practice, anyway, the parameter must be passed as parameter.

Comment: I just wanted it made clear to the OP as to what @DanielA.White is referring to when he says that the code can introduce a [SQL Injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: @astander, Fully agree.

Comment: I can imagine exploiting this vulnerability by manipulating the *DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortDatePattern* Property.

Comment: One way to accomplish this is to make GetDate() the default value for your column.  Then you don't have to pass anything from your app.

Comment: @All if i use update query .. hw ill filter db values datewise

Answer (score 2):

`GETDATE()` is the `SQL SERVER` function and you msut call it directly because the query wll executed on the server.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(("Insert into tablename (Date) values(GETDATE())"), con);
```

Comment: Error                                                                                                                                    Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'primarycol.', table 'Sample.dbo.xxx'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: It is because your table has other non-nullable columns other than the `Date`. You must provide values for that columns also.

Comment: Do you want to INSERT or do you want to UPDATE? Of course, if the other fields are required, you have to specify values for those as well!

Comment: @HamletHakobyan yes your are right but i dont to make change in other columns excpt this date column

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar  I want to Insert , if i update cant filter values  as per date wise.. so must i want to use Insert

Comment: If there are other values in other fields that mean the row exists and you must to update instead of insert. Do you want to change the values of that column in entire table (for all rows)?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan  ..so its not possible to use insert query ok. In my case .i want to filter db values by datewise, if i use update its also not possible ..is anyother way

Comment: Why you think that is impossible? Can you explain your problem in more details?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan thankyou so much for ur reply am newbie m not have much experience in concepts.this concept is not possible know ..wana search any other

Comment: Want to use more then one table?